# Controlling elements in for-loop/.each

Tags: jquery, for-loop, each

In jQuery, having retrieved a number of elements, I iterate through them with a .each loop, after which I spit them out on canvas. However, I need to control the elements in groups, so that out of 100 elements, 10 will get a certain value, another 10 will get a different set of values, and so on.

I can't maintain this level of control in the .each-loop, as far as I know. There's no function that says, for the first x-amount of elements retrieved, do this; and for the rest, do something else.

How should I go about taking control of the elements?

Some code example:

```
function handleData(item) {
    var items = jQuery.parseJSON(item);

    var id = items[0].id;
    var something = items[0].something;

    $.each(items, function(key, value) {

        variableHolder[$counter-1] = value.id;
        variableHolder["intellect"] = value.intellect;

        my_obj[$counter] = example.library.text({

value: "something",
example: "one"

});
```

It's the $counter variable that I need to control. I would like to run it in separate batches. First 20 elements in counter gets one type of values, and so on.

Comment: Please, add the code you have tried so far

Comment: Use `slice(0, 10)` to get a subset of elements. Ref. http://api.jquery.com/slice/

Comment: I don't see how slice can be used in .each for the iteration variable. if I'm mistaken, maybe you could give an example? See my update.

Comment: Can you give us a better example? One with some dummy elements 
 that showcases the issue would be wunderbar.

Comment: You wouldn't use it *inside* an each.  You'd use it before performing an each to control what you are looping over

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much the answer, Taplar. Thanks! If you answer, I'd accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `slice()` method (Ref. http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method to get a subset of elements to loop over, to perform whatever operation you want.  This would be done outside, or before, an each typically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a chunking function like this(explanation in the code snippet)

```
let chunk = ( arr, chunk = 1 ) => arr.reduce( ( acc, value, index, oArr, i = index + 1, s = oArr.slice.bind( oArr ), len = oArr.length ) => {
  ( i % chunk === 0 ) ? acc.push( s( i - chunk, i ) ): ( i === len ) && acc.push( s( i - ( i % chunk ), len ) );
  return acc;
}, [] );

chunk(array, chunk_size);
```

```js
//chunking function
//get the array and size of chunks
//reduce the array.
//the reducer function chunks if index+1 modulus the size of the chunk is zero
//if it is it pushes the chunk of the array using slice. 
//if it is not it evaluates if it is the end of the array using a short-circuit AND( && )
//if it is the end of the array we push what we have left as its own chunk
//always returns the accumulated array.

let chunk = ( arr, chunk = 1 ) => arr.reduce( ( acc, value, index, oArr, i = index + 1, s = oArr.slice.bind( oArr ), len = oArr.length ) => {
  ( i % chunk === 0 ) ? acc.push( s( i - chunk, i ) ): ( i === len ) && acc.push( s( i - ( i % chunk ), len ) );
  return acc;
}, [] );


//grab all the elements and turn them into an array
let elements = Array.from( $(".random") );

//chunk the elements into arrays of 10, the remainder will be dumped into the last array.
//log out each array.
chunk(elements, 10).forEach((arr) => console.log(arr));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="random">1</div>
<div class="random">12</div>
<div class="random">3</div>
<div class="random">45</div>
<div class="random">6</div>
<div class="random">77</div>
<div class="random">88</div>
<div class="random">99</div>
<div class="random">1</div>
<div class="random">12</div>
<div class="random">3</div>
<div class="random">45</div>
<div class="random">6</div>
<div class="random">77</div>
<div class="random">88</div>
<div class="random">99</div>
<div class="random">000</div>
<div class="random">1</div>
<div class="random">12</div>
<div class="random">3</div>
<div class="random">45</div>
<div class="random">6</div>
<div class="random">77</div>
<div class="random">88</div>
<div class="random">99</div>
<div class="random">000</div>
```